# How do I implement a timer for this code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, timer, accelerometer

```
-(void) play
{
    CMMotionManager *motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];

    BOOL timeReached = NO;

    while(!self.stopButtonPressed)
    {
        if(motionManager.deviceMotion.userAcceleration.y >= ... && motionManager.deviceMotion.userAcceleration.y <= ...)
        {
             //start timer
        }
        while(motionManager.deviceMotion.userAcceleration.y >= ... && motionManager.deviceMotion.userAcceleration.y <= ... && !timeReached)
        {
            if(//check timer & if timer is >=300ms)
            {
              timeReached = YES;
              NSLog(@"acceleration on Y-axis stayed between ... & .. for at least 300ms");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've found that NSLog tends to delay things pretty severely. You might be satisfied with the results you get if you remove the logs.

Comment: `clock()` is really bad for timers (because it only counts CPU ticks, which aren't guaranteed to have CLOCKS_PER_SEC every second). Use something like `dispatch_after` instead.

Comment: please have a look at the EDIT at the end of my post, I'm not sure how to implement what you are suggesting in my case..

Comment: I think this will miss the case where x leaves the boundaries, but then returns before time is up.

Comment: I've edited my original post. I believe now it's quite clearer what I'm looking for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're going about this the wrong way; instead of running a clock, you should be setting `accelerometerUpdateInterval` to whatever you're looking for and using `startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:` to receive the data.

From [the Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Handing Motion Updates at Specified Intervals
>
> To receive motion data
> at specific intervals, the application calls a “start” method that
> takes an operation queue (instance of NSOperationQueue) and a block
> handler of a specific type for processing those updates. The motion
> data is passed into the block handler. The frequency of updates is
> determined by the value of an “interval” property.
>
> Accelerometer. Set the accelerometerUpdateInterval property to specify
> an update interval. Call the
> startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler: method, passing in a
> block of type CMAccelerometerHandler. Accelerometer data is passed
> into the block as CMAccelerometerData objects.

Once you've set everything up, let it run. When you've received a completion notice from the block look at the data you've received.

Comment: I'm not running a clock in order to set how often I will be getting acceleration updates (I'm satisfied with the frequency at which they're coming to me right now, using this code). I will be using the clock (or its equivalent) later on (the present code is just for testing purposes) to do something like : `If Acceleration >= x && Acceleration <= x For 300ms... Then Do This...`

Comment: It's not about frequency of updates; you can set that to whatever you want. It seemed like you wanted a precise AMOUNT of time measured, and using a clock you aren't going to get that. The code above explains how to measure acceleration for a precise amount of time.

Comment: I actually want to measure acceleration for a precise amount of time, only if the acceleration being measured stays between certain boundaries as my EDIT at the end of my original post shows, so I'm not sure queuing values will do the job. I think it could be much simpler..

Comment: I have edited my original post to make it clearer and more concrete what it is I'm looking for..